# Error when chaining dplyr operations with pipe (%>%) operatror

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

The pipe operator does not appear to work as advertised in the following operation outlined below:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tibble")
```

I could not automate by code within R, but downloading the 740 row,  32 column excel document indicated below then saving as "rus18.csv"  in your working directory then saving it as "rus18.csv" in your working  directory will allow this code to work

```
path = "https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/2018/2018-general-schedule-pay-rates.xls"
```

Read file as tibble:

```
rus18 <- as_tibble(read.csv("rus18.csv"))
```

verify that dplyr operation works alone. The following two lines do the same thing:

```
filter(rus18, LOCNAME == "RUS") 
rus18 %>% filter(LOCNAME == "RUS")
```

Same with these two:

```
select(rus18, starts_with("HOURLY")) 
rus18 %>% select(starts_with("HOURLY"))
```

But putting them together gives "Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'LOCNAME' not found"

```
rus17 %>% select(starts_with("HOURLY"))  %>% filter(LOCNAME == "RUS")
```

Comment: `rus17 %>% select(starts_with("HOURLY"))` returns a dataframe that does not include the column `LOCNAME` anymore. Include `LOCNAME` in your `select` statement.

Comment: Or just switch the order - filter first, then select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer have the column `LOCNAME` when you chain the two like that. The `select` call has kept only columns with names starting with `"HOURLY"`, so of course there is no more column to check for the value `"RUS"`.

Try this way around:

```
rus17 %>% filter(LOCNAME == "RUS") %>% select(starts_with("HOURLY"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. For some reason, I thought the operations were applied right-to-left/back-to-front instead of as you indicate.

Comment: Probably because that's how you read functions when nested, like `select(filter(rus17, LOCNAME == "RUS"), starts_with("HOURLY"))`. The advantage of the pipe, other than making mismatched parentheses less likely, is being able to read left to right.